# Onclick function automatically added in href in action link tag - Asp.Net Core

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

In Razor View :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", null, null, new { onclick = "Delete(" + item.Id 
+ "); return false;" })
```

In Html page view when I inspect the element,

```
<a href="/Location?onclick=Delete(11);%20return%20false;">Delete</a>
```

I tried a lot of ways, but, I couldn't find any suitable solution! can you help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Html.ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_IHtmlHelper_ActionLink_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) returns an anchor () element that contains a URL path to the specified action. It has the following extension methods ：
[image]

If you want to add Onclick function in action link tag , you should add it after the routevalue in the order of the parameters like below :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Tests",new  { }, new { onclick = "Delete(" + item.Id + "); return false;" })
```